# How do you use a modern version of Vue (Vue CLI3) with Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

The most popular boilerplate for vue/electron usage, seen here: https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue

Is outdated, and only uses vue cli2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest, and easiest way I've found to get Vue and Electron playing nice together is [vue electron-builder](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/).

To use, set up a project with Vue CLI3 using

`vue create my-project`

then CD into that directory, in this case "my-project", and run

`vue add electron-builder`

This sets up barebones scaffolding that allows vue and electron to play nicely from the get go. You can test your work by launching an unbuilt test version using

`npm run electron:serve`

and, when you are ready for deployment, may use

`npm run electron:build`

to build. This vastly simplifies the process, seen elsewhere, of dealing with a giant over engineered boilerplate or trying to write out relative pathing so your builds and dev environments both work identically.

Answer (score 1):

This repository contains the starter template for using vue-next with the latest electron.

I started to learn electron & vue by the great project electron-vue. This project is also inspired from it.

https://github.com/ci010/electron-vue-next